# IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am new to android. I am implementing music player using service. Here is the code in which error is focused. Can anyone help me out to solve this error?

```
public void getSong() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long thisId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            String thisTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String thisArtist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

            int albumId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
            String thisArt = cursor.getString(albumId);

            musicArrayList.add(new Music(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisArt));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: your cusror is null. make sure you have enough media so that cursor filled.

Comment: yeah I checked, it has the enough media so cursor can't be null

Comment: on which line is this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure table in which you are fetching the data having same column name 
Check out this http://www.rjkfw.com/android/s3035.html

Answer (score 0):

Check null before extracting data.

```
ListView audioListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songView);

   ArrayList<string> audioList = new ArrayList<>();

   String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };// Can include more data for more details and check it.

   Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

   if(audioCursor != null){
       if(audioCursor.moveToFirst()){
           do{
               int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

               audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
           }while(audioCursor.moveToNext());
       }
   }
   audioCursor.close();

   ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, audioList);
   audioListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved, Since I was looking for album of particular song, null value is passed in cursor. so I changed my code of cursor as below:

```
public void getSong() {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM},
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1",
                null,
                null);


        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long thisId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                String thisTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String thisArtist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String thisImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));

                songList.add(new Music(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisImage));
}while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

And I have tried by calling getsongImage(URI) method in playSong() in service class for getting Album as below:

```
public void getSongImage(Uri uri) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(this,uri);
        byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if(data==null){
            activitySongDetailBinding.imgMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
        }else {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            activitySongDetailBinding.imgMusic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

where uri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, songsArrayList.get(songPosn).getId())